# I cant get the right time in php

Tags: php, time

I am new to PHP and I am having a timing problem in my code. Right now the time on my computer and in my time zone is 10:43 but when I use this php code to display time info I get 1:43:27

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo date('H:i:s');
```

in my php.ini file I have this

I just changed where it says date.timezone

```
; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions
date.timezone = America/New_York
; http://php.net/date.timezone
date.timezone = UTC

; http://php.net/date.default-latitude
;date.default_latitude = 31.7667

; http://php.net/date.default-longitude
;date.default_longitude = 35.2333

; http://php.net/date.sunrise-zenith
;date.sunrise_zenith = 90.583333
```

I thought the above code would fix this time problem. I also stopped and started WAMP before  and after I changed the .ini file.

Thank You.

Comment: Since you use `date_default_timezone_set`, the timezone in php.ini is irrelevant.

Comment: Thanks for answering i commented out // date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York'); in php file and now I get 6:58 I would like it to be my time 10:58. wondering whats wrong

Comment: Are you using a very old version of PHP?

Comment: I have version 5.4.3 I commented ;date.timezone = America/New_York in the .ini file. and have-- date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
echo date('H:i:s'); in php file now. I get 2:13

Comment: It looks to me that in php.ini you are setting date.timezone twice, ultimately to UTC.

Comment: You are overwriting the timezone. Either use `date.timezone = America/New_York` or `date.timezone = UTC`, right now `UTC` is being used.

Comment: I deleted `date.timezone = UTC` and it's still not working for me.

Comment: I believe the problem was that I was using localhost. is there away for me to get the right time on localhost? fyi uploaded it to a remote server and it worked but not on localhost.

Answer (score 0):

I use `ini_set("date.timezone","America/New_York")`

Comment: You put this in the .ini file? under the line where it says `; Defines the default timezone used by the date functions`?

Comment: @user2537537 No, `ini_set()` is a way of changing php.ini values from within the PHP script.

Comment: Put it in your php script maybe in your config.php

Comment: tried that still getting 02:26:37 and I would like 11:27. thanks for your help though